# How to get current culture string values from recource file?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In MVC I'm setting up first time like below:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
    rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
    ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    LoadString(ci);
    return View();
}
```

By clicking 'french' button I want to change language from English to French, so I'm going by jQuery like below:

```
$("#btnFrench").click(function () {
    alert();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ToFrench", "Home")",
        traditional: true,//data: {},
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });
    function successFunc(status) {//data,
       var name = '@TempData["Name"]';
       alert(name);
    }
    function errorFunc() {
       alert("Operation Failed!");
    }
});
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ToFrench()
{
    rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
    ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    LoadString(ci);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr");

    LoadString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

So, in below code I cann't get French values from French resource file.

```
private void LoadString(CultureInfo ci)
{

    string naam = rm.GetString("Name", ci);
    TempData["Name"] = naam;
    ViewBag.Gender = rm.GetString("Gender", ci);
    ViewBag.DateOfBirth = rm.GetString("DateOfBirth", ci);
    ViewBag.About = rm.GetString("About", ci);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You seem to be loading the resource OK. Please describe exactly what is happening and how that differs from what you want.

Comment: in last step code i described my problem, i wanna convert that 'Name' to french language 'prénom', where i set it in 'fr.resx' resource file.

Comment: Please note I asked you to describe the *current behaviour and how it differs*: are you getting an error, nothing, some unexpected value?

Comment: Your making an ajax call - ajax calls never redirect (the whole point is to stay on the same page). And `var name = '@TempData["Name"]';` returns the value you first passed to the view.

Comment: And why are you putting those values in `ViewBag` - how are they being used in your view?

Comment: no need to redirect na, i just want value by load 'LoadString' methode, in that iam using tempdata to store values, but the issue is iam getting same english language values, where have to get french language values.

Comment: outting in viewbag because replace the values in view from eng-french.

Comment: You still have not explained in your question what your trying to do! And what are those values used for?

Answer (score 1):

You are making an `ajax` request and trying to access `@TempData["Name"]` in the callback.
Ajax requests are invoked in the client side (browser), while `@TempData["Name"]` is `razor` and rendered in the server.

I would rethink this approach, if you don't mind posting again instead of re-render the whole page in the client (this will refresh the page) you can pass a URL parameter in your requests and grab it in `global.asax` inside `Application_BeginRequest()` method, which will catch each request to the server, in this method you can set the culture according to the URL.
For example: 
if the url has a query string of `?lang=fra` then you will set the culture respectively.
Example Code of `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var cs = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    // set culture based on query-string lang parameter
    var calture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures).SingleOrDefault(c => c.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(Request["Lang"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (calture != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = calture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = calture;
    }
}
```

Inside your views you just reference the resource files.
Let's say you got a `Titles.resx` and `Titles.fr.resx` files and you got a key with the name of `Submit`, then you will use it like this:  `Titles.Submit`.
The mvc engine will pick up the `resx` file according to the culture.